# Tor Browser failed to start under Selenium

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, browsers, python

Trying to connect to tor via selenium for the first time. Using Windows 7 64 ...Getting this error code..

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 0
```

and a pop-up saying tor failed to start. Here is my code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe')
torexe = os.popen(r'C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe')
profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9150)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile= profile, executable_path=r'C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\geckodriver.exe', firefox_binary=binary)
driver.get("http://check.torproject.org")
```

Any help is appreciated.Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to have tor browser running before hand** .

This will connect via tor and load your profile so that google,FB etc opens with you already logged in. This is working as of today on win7 64 bit.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
profile = FirefoxProfile("C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\ogwfse3l.default-release")
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9150)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.gmail.com')
```